# App Script Card Service - How to know what grid item was clicked?

Tags: google-apps-script, grid, gmail

looking at this code, how do I know which item was clicked??

By the selected item I will be doing some calls to an api service, can you help me with that please?

```
CardService.newGrid()
  .setTitle("title")                                  
  .setBorderStyle(CardService.newBorderStyle().setType(CardService.BorderType.STROKE))
  .setOnClickAction(
          CardService.newAction()
             .setFunctionName("testGrid"))
  .setNumColumns(2)
  .addItem(CardService.newGridItem()
                   .setTitle("X1"))
  .addItem(CardService.newGridItem()
                   .setTitle("X2"))
  .addItem(CardService.newGridItem()
                   .setTitle("Y3"))
  .addItem(CardService.newGridItem()
                   .setTitle("Y4"))

function testGrid(e){
 console.log("How do I know which item is?");
}
```

Comment: I'd look at `function testGrid(e) { Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e);}`

Comment: Already did it :\
   * comunEvent
   * formInput/formInputs
   * gmail
   * hostApp
   * clientPlatform
   * messageMetadata
The likely canditates should be inputForm or inputForms, but come empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, and it was a mistake on my part:

```
CardService.newGrid()
  .setTitle("title")                                  
  .setBorderStyle(CardService.newBorderStyle().setType(CardService.BorderType.STROKE))
  .setOnClickAction(
          CardService.newAction()
             .setFunctionName("testGrid"))
  .setNumColumns(2)
  .addItem(CardService.newGridItem()
                   .setTitle("X1")
                   .setIdentifier("idX1"))
  .addItem(CardService.newGridItem()
                   .setTitle("X2")
                   .setIdentifier("idX2"))
  .addItem(CardService.newGridItem()
                   .setTitle("Y3")
                   .setIdentifier("idY3"))
  .addItem(CardService.newGridItem()
                   .setTitle("Y4")
                   .setIdentifier("idY4"))

function testGrid(e){
  if(e.parameters.grid_item_identifier == "idY4"){
    console.log("Y4 clicked!!!!");
  }
   
}
```

Comment: Good catch.  Sorry I could not help more.  I don't use the card service very often

Comment: No problem, but thanks anyway :)